# Google Places Javascript API get the response status

Tags: javascript, google-places-api

I've seen ways to get the API status when using the JSON or XML version of the Google Places API responses. Mainly the examples show trying to display a map:

```
new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
service.nearbySearch(request, callback);

function callback(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      var place = results[i];
      createMarker(results[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

But to just have a Google places autocomplete field in javascript you use the js request url:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY;libraries=places&amp;callback=initAutocomplete
```

Then create the autocomplete object and call getPlace():

```
var autoComplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(<html input element>);
autoComplete.getPlace();
```

However, I don't see any status option embedded in the javascript object returned by:

```
autoComplete.getPlace();
```

I've searched the Google Places Javascript API and there's mention of the statuses

> The PlacesServiceStatus response object contains the status of the request, and may contain debugging information to help you track down why the Place Details request failed. Possible status values are:
>
> ERROR: There was a problem contacting the Google servers.
>
> INVALID_REQUEST: This request was invalid.
>
> OK: The response contains a valid result.
>
> OVER_QUERY_LIMIT: The webpage has gone over its request quota.
>
> NOT_FOUND The referenced location was not found in the Places database.
>
> REQUEST_DENIED: The webpage is not allowed to use the PlacesService.
>
> UNKNOWN_ERROR: The PlacesService request could not be processed due to a server error. The request may succeed if you try again.
>
> ZERO_RESULTS: No result was found for this request.

I'd really like to have error handling in place in the case of any of these statuses being returned. Is this a limitation of using the Javascript API?

Comment: Great question. Almost 4 years later, this is still relevant and unresolved in their API docs. I use `var place = this.getPlace(); if (place) { ... }` ... but it's unclear whether or not this handles errors correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be somewhat less than elegant but, having not so far found a better answer, I am currently using this:

```
if (google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK === "OK") {

        // my code here

}
```